# Is "past master" a gender neutral phrase?

Tags: word-usage, gender-neutral

> PAST MASTER - noun: a person who has done something many times before and has become very skilled at doing it "He's a past master at finding ways to get out of trouble."
>   http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/past%20master
>
> noun: A person who is particularly skilled at a specified activity or art.A person who has held the position of master in an organization
>   ‘he’s a past master at keeping his whereabouts secret’
>   http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/past-master

I always thought "past master" was a gender neutral phrase applied to both men and women, and "past mistress" would refer to a past lover.  I've heard "past mistress" in reference to women, though, and it had no love connotation. Has "past master" lost its "gender neutral" property? Or am I  wrong and it never had any?

Comment: As much as "person" in the definitions is. Why the question now? As for *mistress,* that's a long story, nothing to do with 'past master' alone.

Comment: As people have wised up and recognized women's mastery over the full spectrum of performance, *master* has come to be gender neutral. If someone is creating the neologistic phrase *past mistress*, it's an indication of a retrograde slide into sexual distinction that is without semantic, logical or social value.

Comment: What makes you ask this question? You always thought it was gender neutral, the two definitions you found state it as gender neutral, so **what** makes you think that it is not gender neutral anymore? The simple fact that there are people out there that still think it is necessary to give women a separate word for the same concept?  That is their problem, not yours :)

Comment: @oerkelens   What made me ask this question?  Because I found "past mistress" in a dictionary.  That should be a good reason.  PAST MISTRESS  a woman who is proficient or thorough in some particular respect :  adept <a past mistress of storytelling http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/past%20mistress

Comment: Ah, the _past mistress_ dictionary reference is more of an indication of its actual use than "I heard it used", so maybe it deserves to be mentioned in the question :) That said, I think FF's answer says it all :)

Comment: @oerkelens  I heard it used and rushed to search for it in dicitionaries. When I found it and decided to post the question here, I thought it better no to mention the dictionary entry to make sure I would get unbiased answers. And I suppose anyone who is not 100% sure of what he is writing will certainly search the www.

Comment: For what it is worth, "Past Master" is a very specific title in Freemasonry.   It is given to any man (and it is ALWAYS a man since Freemasonry is, above all, a fraternity) who has served as Master of the Lodge.   Those who hold the title include the initials P.M. when signing any documents related to Lodge activities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The editors at [Chambers Universal Learners' Dictionary](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=AB1f965CUnwC&pg=PA519&dq=%22skill%20she%20is%20a%20past%20master%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GD41VISnNMrY7Ab_zoGgCA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22skill%20she%20is%20a%20past%20master%22&f=false) obviously anticipated precisely this kind of misguided literal-mindedness when choosing their example usage...

> **a past master** - someone who is extremely skilful (at an activity which requires skill)
>    ***She*** is a past master at the art of getting her own way

Emphasis mine, but I think it's reasonable to suppose the editors intended to *imply* the same.

---

FWIW, Google Books claims over 10,000 written instances of [*"she is a past master"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20fool%20for%20an%20editor%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22she%20is%20a%20past%20master%22). Which may not mean much - it initially claims 1840 instances of [*"she is a past mistress"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22she%20is%20a%20past%20mistress%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), but if I scroll through there are [actually only 33](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22she%20is%20a%20past%20mistress%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22she%20is%20a%20past%20mistress%22&tbm=bks&start=30) (almost all from the last decade or two, reflecting modern "anti-sexist" usages by some writers).

Comment: Interestingly, that "anti-sexist" usage tends to be seen as sexist by others (including leading feminists).

Comment: Before anyone else, in addition to @oerklens, asks why I'm asking this question, let me say that I heard it and then searched for its meaning: PAST MISTRESS a woman who is proficient or thorough in some particular respect : adept <a past mistress of storytelling merriam-webster.com/dictionary/past%20mistress    That made me wonder, because I had always thought "past master" was gender neutral.

Comment: @user463240: You have to bear in mind that any language reflects the society/culture of its *speakers*. And realistically, Anglophone societies 150 years ago when the usage first arose were *not* "gender neutral" in the way they are today. Some people are bothered by this in some contexts, which is why they try to introduce the rather quirky alternative *past mistress*. But so far I've never heard anyone seriously complain about the *verb* usage in contexts like *By the age of 12 she had mastered the piano*.

Comment: It would be hilarious to hear "she had mistressed the piano".

Comment: I understand that, FF. What surprised me was that I heard it and thought it didn't exist. But when I searched, there it was in a dictionary.

Comment: @user463240: You'll like this 1856 usage then! :) [*This one {this girl learning the art of gilding} is a firstrate gilder, she **mistressed** it entirely in three days*.](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=jhVHAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA52&dq=%22she+mistressed+it+entirely%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mls1VPb4JKPg7QaY34CQDw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22she%20mistressed%20it%20entirely%22&f=false). But I really wouldn't like to say if there's any element of "facetiousness" there.

Comment: Good call.  There must be a phrase for digging up a word, phrase or saying that hasn't been heard for ages. In my mother tongue we would say "He dug it up from the bottom of the well".